# ::after pseudo class not being properly applied to an anchor tag for hover animation

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I want a red underline to display below my "BOOK NOW" anchor tag when a user hovers over it and also the text color to change to white. For some reason, the text color is not changing. I also noticed that the width of the underline which I specified as a 100%, is actually taking 100% of it's parent element and also the underline is way below the anchor tag, it is just above the place where the parent element ends.

Here's my HTML and CSS code

```css
/* Hero Section */

#hero {
  color: white;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 0 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#hero h1{
  margin:0;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom:3rem;
  width: 40%;
}

#hero p{
  margin:0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 30%;
}

#hero a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e50914;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#hero a:hover,{
  color:white;
}

#hero a:hover::after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}
.video-gradient{
}


.back-video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="why.html">Why Snap Smile</a></li>
        <li><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="hero">
    <h1>Get Your Hollywood Smile Today</h2>
    <p>Show off your million dollar smile with your Snap Smile Veneers</p>
    <a href="#">BOOK NOW</a>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to stick to your current HTML structure, all you need to do is to add the `position` property to your `#hero a` selector and give it the value of `relative`. Modify your properties for your `#hero a:hover::after` selector into

```
#hero a:hover::after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
```

You can learn more about CSS positions by reading through these articles by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-link-hover-effects/).

The reason the colour of your link is not changing on the hover state is because of the extra comma just before the curly braces on your selector. Remove this and everything should work as expected.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}

/* Header Section */
#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 80px;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6629026610644257) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,0) 57%);
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
  color: #e50914;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 20px;
}

.logo {
  width: 10rem;
}

/* Hero Section */

#hero {
  color: white;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 0 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#hero h1{
  margin:0;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom:3rem;
  width: 40%;
}

#hero p{
  margin:0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 30%;
}

#hero a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e50914;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
}

#hero a:hover {
  color:white;
}

#hero a:hover::after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.video-gradient{
}


.back-video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Snap Smile</title>
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Styles Sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6b5d823830.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="why.html">Why Snap Smile</a></li>
        <li><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="hero">
    <h1>Get Your Hollywood Smile Today</h2>
    <p>Show off your million dollar smile with your Snap Smile Veneers</p>
    <a href="#">BOOK NOW</a>
    <!-- <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="back-video">
      <source src="Videos/banner-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video> -->
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your code first without specifying the 'left' property and I saw the the underline began, just from the point where the anchor tag ends, and when I specified 'left' as 0px. It was at the right position. Why is that so?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean but to verify you did want to achieve a line to appear underneath your "Book Now" link, right? I went ahead and pasted your code with the fixes I added to achieve this and it seems to be working. Let me know if I misunderstood something!

Comment: Yes, I just have a confusion, you specified the 'left' position property in your code; "left: 0;" Well I pasted the code you gave and I removed the 'left' property and I noticed that the underline was not in the correct position, it started from the point where the anchor tag ended whereas it should have started from the point where the anchor tag started, I wanted to know why this happens.

Comment: Oh! That has something to do with the fact that you used the ::after pseudo element. This means that naturally, if you remove properties specifying the position of the element, it will be located after the end of the text "Book Now". You can see this if you made it so that it is visible without the user hovering on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You had your CSS selector wrong `#hero a:hover,{ ... }` it shouldn't have the comma after "hover"

I also cleaned up the underline and made it fade in on hover

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}


/* Header Section */

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 80px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6629026610644257) 0%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 0) 57%);
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
  color: #e50914;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #e50914;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 20px;
}

.logo {
  width: 10rem;
}


/* Hero Section */

#hero {
  color: white;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 0 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  width: 40%;
}

#hero p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 30%;
}

#hero a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e50914;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#hero a::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#hero a:hover { color: white }
#hero a:hover::after { background: #e50914 }

.video-gradient {}

.back-video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 80%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6b5d823830.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="why.html">Why Snap Smile</a></li>
        <li><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="hero">
    <h1>Get Your Hollywood Smile Today</h2>
      <p>Show off your million dollar smile with your Snap Smile Veneers</p>
      <a href="#">BOOK NOW</a>
      <!-- <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="back-video">
      <source src="Videos/banner-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video> -->
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have 2 questions - 1. Why not specify the background color of the underline in just one block i.e. #hero a:hover::after{} instead of, first specifying #hero a::after and then #hero a:hover::after 2. Why did you set the background as 'transparent' in #hero a:after{}

Comment: @SahilSingh so that the opacity color could fade in from transparent to red